# Filters in Express js routing

Tags: node.js, express, url-routing

I am new to express js. Is there a way to configure the app to support filters at different points of the url. Let me be more clear in my question

Lets say I have

```
                app.get('/path1/*' , function1)
                app.get('/path1/path2/*' , function2)
                app.get('/path1/path2/path3/*' , function3)
```

When I say `http://mydomain.com/path1/path2/path3/path4 GET` ,

I need function1 , function2 , function 3 to be executed in order.

Is there a way I can achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will work fine just preserve the order in which you want them to execute and make sure earlier functions do not end the response. The functions should have arguments `(req,res,next)` and must call `next();` when you want next one to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
app.get('/path1/path2/path3/path4' , function1, function2, function3)
```

Hence the functions will execute in order.